# ¿Por qué sale el error: Caused by: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1?

Tags: java, json, jsonobject, gson

tengo un campo String llamado **muestra** que contiene lo siguiente

```
{"listPruebas": [

    {
      "nombrePrueba" : "pruebaA",

      "id" : 1,

      "tipoPrueba" : "PRUEBABASE1",

      "elementoBase" : "tipoA",

            "listaMarca": [

            {

                "elemento": "elemento1 ",

                "tipo": "ABC",

                "cadena": "SFSG34235WF32"

            },

            {

                 "elemento":"elemento2",

                 "tipo":"DEF",

                 "cadena":"DJRT64353GSDG"

            },

            {

                "elemento" : "elemento3",

                "formato ":"JPG"


            }

    },

    {

      "nombrePrueba" : "pruebaB",

      "id" : 2,

      "tipoPrueba" : "PRUEBABASE2",

      "elementoBase" : "imagenPrueba",

            "listaMarca2": [

               {

                   "elemento" : "imagen",

                   "tipo": "tipo5",

                   "cadena": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAA"

                }

            ]
    }



            ],



                "listaBuscar":

                [

                {

                               "tipoBusqueda":"busqueda1",

                               "id" : 1,

                               "operacion" : "operacion1",

                               "valor" : "12"

                },

                {

                               "tipoBusqueda":"binario",

                               "id" : 2,

                               "operacion" : "operacion2",

                               "valor" : "13"

                },

                {

                               "tipoFiltro":"numerico",

                               "id" : 31,

                               "operacion" : "MENOR_QUE",

                               "valor" : "1980",

                               "intervalo" : 1

                }

                ],

  ]


}
```

Lo que hice fue convertir ese String en un json string de la siguiente manera

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonMuestra = gson.toJson(muestra);
```

Y ahora necesito convertir ese JSON String en JSONObject, por lo cual hice lo siguiente

```
JSONObject objet = new JSONObject(jsonMuestra);
```

pero me marca este error, que hice mal?

```
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1

       at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:413)

       at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:180)
```

Answer (score -1):

Probablemente el json este mal formado, puedes comprobarlo en la siguiente web:
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
Te lo dejo bien formateado por aquí.

```
{"listPruebas": [

    {
      "nombrePrueba" : "pruebaA",

      "id" : 1,

      "tipoPrueba" : "PRUEBABASE1",

      "elementoBase" : "tipoA",

            "listaMarca": [

            {

                "elemento": "elemento1 ",

                "tipo": "ABC",

                "cadena": "SFSG34235WF32"

            },

            {

                 "elemento":"elemento2",

                 "tipo":"DEF",

                 "cadena":"DJRT64353GSDG"

            },

            {

                "elemento" : "elemento3",

                "formato ":"JPG"


            }

    ]},

    {

      "nombrePrueba" : "pruebaB",

      "id" : 2,

      "tipoPrueba" : "PRUEBABASE2",

      "elementoBase" : "imagenPrueba",

            "listaMarca2": [

               {

                   "elemento" : "imagen",

                   "tipo": "tipo5",

                   "cadena": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAA"

                }

            ]
    }



            ],



                "listaBuscar":

                [

                {

                               "tipoBusqueda":"busqueda1",

                               "id" : 1,

                               "operacion" : "operacion1",

                               "valor" : "12"

                },

                {

                               "tipoBusqueda":"binario",

                               "id" : 2,

                               "operacion" : "operacion2",

                               "valor" : "13"

                },

                {

                               "tipoFiltro":"numerico",

                               "id" : 31,

                               "operacion" : "MENOR_QUE",

                               "valor" : "1980",

                               "intervalo" : 1

                }

                ],




}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: gracias ya lo corregi pero al querer convertirlo en JSONObject sale lo mismo